# Making 2D plots with pcolor from scattered points

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, colormap

I have a fortran program that simulates some kind of radiation in the air and the signal obtained in each of the antennas at the ground. I am reading the output data with Python3, and one of the output *.dat* files holds information about the antennas, and it is organized in columns (Position along X-axis, Position along Y-axis, Signal detected, etc).

Supose that I have ~ 1000000 antennas and I have already storaged the position and signal of every one of them in the lists `column_x` ,`column_y`,`signal` and my objective is to reproduce a plot like the following:

[image: Example plot]

**How can I do that?**

I tried to make a matrix with shape `(len(column_x),len(column_y))`, insert the values of the list `signal` in each place of the antenna and plot that matrix with `plt.pcolor` but I had a lot of issues. There must be an easiest way.

Comment: Unless the positions are discretized (i.e. integer values) then you will have to create a 
regular grid and resample the data to that grid in order to use `pcolor` (or `pcolormesh`, `pcolorfast`, etc). If they are not discretized then a scatter plot is the alternative.  If your primary concern is the regions of high density you can create a scatter plot which effectively highlights them - particularly by using translucent markers (by passing `alpha < 1.0` in `plt.scatter`)

Comment: Apart from a scatter plot, also [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html) can be interesting. It can accept lists of x, y and z (the signal) positions and creates 2D areas (contours) depending on the signal. (x and y don't need to be organized as a grid)

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to do is exactly what matplotlib.pyplot.scatter can do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(column_x, column_y, c=signal)
```